# Convergence of this series through comparison

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial

How can I give some estimation of the convergence of this series, only using comparison and majorisation of the terms?

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$

I tried with

$$(n!)^2 = n^2\cdot (n-1)^2\cdot (n-2)^2 \ldots \leq n^2\cdot n^2\ \cdot n^2 \ldots = (n^2)^2 = n^{2n}$$

So $$\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} \leq \frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!} \qquad \text{for} n \geq 4$$

Yet I don't find a suitable majorisation for the denominator; I can only think of

$$(2n)! = 2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2) \ldots \geq n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2) \ldots = n!$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{(2n)!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}$$

But then I am not able to go on.

- I only can/want to use comparison in this sense, and/or at the end comparison with exponential or harmonic series.
- If this could be turned, somehow, into a geometric series (via some estimation / majorisation) it would be AWESOME
- I cannot use Stirling or other criteria.
- Not allowed to use binomial coefficient, ratio test and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: @lulu Thank you Lulu for the link. Unfortunately, we haven't studied the binomial coefficient, hence "we cannot use it" (I know it sounds stupid, but our professor only wants we to use what he taught in class, hence the above demands from me...)

Comment: The ratio test does not require the use of binomial symbols, simple algebra suffices.

Comment: @lulu "No ratio test or other criteria" :)

Comment: The rules seem arbitrary.  If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L<1$ then you can compare the series to the geometric series $\sum L^n$.  You don't need to use the phrase "ratio test" .  Or, as the solution from @ThomasAndrews shows, you can just show directly that $\frac {(n!)^2}{(2n)!}<\frac {n+1}{4^n}$ and do it that way.  In any case, I suggest adapting one or more of the posted solutions to comply with the rule set.

Comment: @lulu You used the ratio test, which I cannot use (we didn't even study it). So how to do it without the ratio test? Becasue this is basically what you used. We have been taught only to use comparison and majorisations, no tricks like that one. 
Also, could you look at the comment I posted on the upvoted answer please? I cannot understand why my derivation is wrong, which would lead to the divergence of the series btw.

Comment: Your computation may be correct, but it's irrelevant.  Knowing that $a_n<b_n$ where $\sum b_n$ diverges  tells us nothing.  $\sum a_n$ might converge or it might diverge.  The posted solution, from @WADon looks fine, and it is straight comparison (as some of the posted solutions in the duplicate were as well).

Comment: For a concrete example, we have $\frac 1{n^2} ≤ \frac 1n$, (and strictly $<$ for $n>1$), but $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$ converges whlle $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match pairs of terms in the numerator and denominator, writing,
\begin{align}
\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} = 
\left(\frac{n}{2n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2n-2}\cdots\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot
\left(
\frac{n}{2n-1}\cdot \frac{n-1}{2n-3}\cdots\frac{1}{1}\right)
\end{align}
where each term in the first parentheses is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and each term (except the last) in the second is less than $1$.  Thus, for $n \geqslant 1$
\begin{align}
\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} \leqslant \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align}
The sum you want is then increasing (all terms are positive) and bounded above by a convergent geometric series.  Thus it must also be convergent.

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't actually know why is this correct. I mean what if I wrote
$$\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} = \frac{n}{2n}\cdot \frac{(n-1)^2}{2n-1} \cdot \frac{(n-2)^2}{2n-2} \ldots$$ 

In this case I would have the terms $\frac{(n-k)^2}{2n-k} \leq \frac{n}{2}$ and so for every term, hence in the end

$$\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} \leq \frac{n^n}{2^n}$$

Whence the serie would diverge. Why is this wrong then?

Comment: @Numb3rs you can't conclude that it's divergent

Comment: @SineoftheTime Right! My bad, got it!